# Delete or remove unexpected records and strings based on multiple criteria by python or R script

Tags: python-2.7, csv, record

I have a `.csv` file named `fileOne.csv` that contains many unnecessary strings and records. I want to delete unnecessary records / rows and strings based on multiple condition / criteria using a Python or R script and save the records into a new `.csv` file named `resultFile.csv`.

What I want to do is as follows:

1. Delete the first column.
2. Split column BB into two column named as `a_id`, and `c_id`. Separate the value by _ (underscore) and left side will go to `a_id`, and right side will go to `c_id`.
3. Keep only records that have the .csv file extension in the files column, but do not contain `No Bi` in cut column.
4. Assign new name to each of the columns.
5. Delete the records that contain strings like `less` in the CC column.
6. Trim all other unnecessary string from the records.
7. Delete the reamining filds of each rows after I find the "Mi" in each rows.

My `fileOne.csv` is as follows:

```
   AA      BB       CC       DD     EE      FF    GG
   1       1_1.csv  (=0      =10"   27"     =57   "Mi"
   0.97    0.9      0.8      NaN    0.9     od    0.2
   2       1_3.csv  (=0      =10"   27"     "Mi"  0.5
   0.97    0.5      0.8      NaN    0.9     od    0.4
   3       1_6.csv  (=0      =10"   "Mi"     =53  cnt
   0.97    0.9      0.8      NaN    0.9     od    0.6
   4       2_6.csv  No Bi    000    000     000   000
   5       2_8.csv  No Bi    000    000     000   000
   6       6_9.csv  less     000    000     000   000
   7       7_9.csv  s(=0     =26"   =46"    "Mi"  121
```

My 1st expected results files would be as follows:

```
a_id    b_id    CC    DD    EE    FF    GG             
1       1       0     10    27    57    Mi              
1       3       0     10    27    Mi    0.5
1       6       0     10    Mi    53    cnt 
7       9       0     26    46    Mi    121
```

My final expected results files would be as follows:

```
a_id    b_id    CC    DD    EE    FF    GG             
1       1       0     10    27    57              
1       3       0     10    27
1       6       0     10 
7       9       0     26    46
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the following Python script:

```
import csv
import re
import string

output_header = ['a_id', 'b_id', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'GG']

sanitise_table = string.maketrans("","")
nodigits_table = sanitise_table.translate(sanitise_table, string.digits)

def sanitise_cell(cell):
    return cell.translate(sanitise_table, nodigits_table)       # Keep digits

with open('fileOne.csv') as f_input, open('resultFile.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    input_header = next(f_input)
    csv_output.writerow(output_header)

    for row in csv_input:
        bb = re.match(r'(\d+)_(\d+)\.csv', row[1])

        if bb and row[2] not in ['No Bi', 'less']:
            # Remove all columns after 'Mi' if present
            try:
                mi = row.index('Mi')
                row[:] = row[:mi] + [''] * (len(row) - mi)
            except ValueError:
                pass

            row[:] = [sanitise_cell(col) for col in row]
            row[0] = bb.group(1)
            row[1] = bb.group(2)
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

To simply remove `Mi` columns from an existing file the following can be used:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv_input:
        try:
            mi = row.index('Mi')
            row[:] = row[:mi] + [''] * (len(row) - mi)
        except ValueError:
            pass

        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Tested using Python 2.7.9

Comment: Hello Evans,
Thank you very much.
I got a simple error as follows, please take a look:

sanitise_table = string.maketrans("","")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'

Comment: Try using Python 2.x.

Comment: Hello Evans,

Thank you. I have run the program in python 2.7.10. There is no error now. But the program produce only he header into the new file.
May be there is a small problem. Could you please take a look.

Thanks

Comment: This means your input file does not match the sample data you have given in the question. If you add `print bb` I am guessing it will be `None`. It is looking for `X_Y.csv` as a filename.

Comment: Hello Evans,

Thank you. Based on your sample, finally I have correct my data fram and got the result. I need a little more work. I find tha I do not need any informaion after I find 'Mi' in each records. Mi means Missing. So, after Missing I do not need any field value in each records. That means delete everythin all after find 'Mi'. Could you please let me know how I can do this in a separate python program, i.e., an individual program to do this task. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Evans,
Thank you. I find a simple error as follow. In addition, is it possible to write a separate program to delete from Mi. I may need it to use it different purpose.
  
File "fileONe.py", line 28
    except ValueError, e:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Depending on your Python version, trying removing `, e` from the line, or replacing it with `as e`

Comment: Evans, Thank you very much. Great and excellent! I have got the result.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello Evans,

Another simple point. Is it possible if I want to take only records which have this condition. For instance, in my fileOne.csv (above) I have many records, finally I find that I only need the records which have "Mi". So, based on condition 'Mi',  I can take all the records which has "Mi" and then remove fields from 'Mi'.  Is this possible?

Comment: It is very straight forward, but to avoid confusion on this question (for other readers), I suggest you start a new question.

Comment: Hello Evans,
I posted a nes thread in the following url.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176960/select-records-based-on-the-specific-index-string-value-and-then-remove-subseque