# moving average of 3 elements by C or Python

Tags: python, c, average, element, convolution

I want to calculate the moving average of 3 elements.

For example, I have a 25 elements of sales data. I need to calculate the moving average taken from averaging these 25 elements of data.

When a real array is given as data, I want to write a program that will determines a 3 element moving average and creates an array. The number of elements in the array becomes 2 elements shorter than the given sequence. 
For example, if I am given:

```
[7.0, 9.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0]
```

I want to get:

```
[7.0, 5.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: this is not about 'c' so please remove the `c` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Python [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=deque#collections.deque) for doing this as follows:

```
from collections import deque

prices = [7.0, 9.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0]
moving_average = deque()
total = 0.0
days = 3
averages = []

for price in prices:
    moving_average.append(price)
    total += price

    if len(moving_average) > days:      # Length of moving average
        total -= moving_average.popleft()

    averages.append(total / float(len(moving_average)))

print averages
```

This would display the following output:

```
[7.0, 8.0, 7.0, 5.0, 3.0]
```

Or you could skip the initial entries as follows:

```
print averages[days-1:]
```

Giving:

```
[7.0, 5.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: Thank you Evans. I have confirmed the results.

Comment: Hello Evans,

I have another simple problem that explained in a new thread in the following link. Could you please take a look.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745521/calculate-the-function-of-fi

Answer (score 3):

The best (and fastest, by far) way to approach this is [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). Using [numpy's convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html):

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.asarray([7.0, 9.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0])

# create what's known as the convolution 'kernel'
# note that this sums to 1, which results in an average
kernel = np.ones(3) / 3

# do the convolution to compute the moving average
moving_avg = np.convolve(x, kernel, mode='valid')
```

You can view the convolution operation as the kernel "sliding" over the data sequence. Every point `moving_avg[k]` in the output of the convolution will be the area under the product between your data and the kernel, when the kernel is centered at that point `k`.

This is an animation (from the wikipedia article linked above) illustrating the principle for the square kernel used in moving average computation:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension is a pythonic way to do this, that does not require any import:

```
>>> a
[7, 9, 5, 1, 3]
>>> [(a[i]+a[i+1]+a[i+2])/3.0 for i in xrange(len(a)-2)]
[7.0, 5.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: This is an elegant and Pythonic way to do it, but will be extremely slow for large data sets. In those cases, the convolution approach which I outlined would be the only way to go. But apart from that, great answer :)