# Calculate the function of f(i)

Tags: function, fibonacci

When i is a positive integer, there is a function f(i) that satisfy the following.

```
f(0) = 0,
f(1) = 1
f(i) = f(i-1) + f(i-2)
```

So, based on the above, I want to write a program to determine f(i). 
And write a program to determine f(1000).

Comment: What programming language, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Python 3.0 script will work:

```
def f(i):
    a, b = 0, 1

    for i in range(i):
        a, b = b, a + b

    return a

print(f(0))
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
print(f(1000))
```

Giving you:

```
0
1
1
2
```

and

> 43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875

Comment: Evans, my explanation might not clear. So, I have revised my explanation so that the problem can be understood easily. Could you please take a look on the revised question above.

Comment: I have updated, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be leaving the programming language open, I choose python which is great for these things.

You can simply do:

```
def f(i):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    elif i == 1:
        return 1
    return f(i-1)+f(i-2)
```

If you want to be more fancy and efficient, use iterators:

```
def f():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:            
        yield a            
        a, b = b, a + b
```

The code runs very fast:

```
for i, val in enumerate(f()):
    if i == 1000:
        print val
        break
```

and return your desired value f(1000), which is:

> 43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875

@DmitryBychenko: the value you returned is actually f(999).

@MartinEvans: your code is actually incorrect (off by 1). One obvious way to see it is that the values returned by f(1) and f(2) are wrong:

```
>>> def f(i):
...     a,b = 0, 1
...     for i in range(i-1):
...             a,b = b, a+b
...     return a
... 
>>> f(0)
0
>>> f(1)
0
>>> f(2)
1
>>> f(3)
1
```

Comment: What are `a` and `b` types? If they are integers you'll have an *overflow*, if they are double you'll *loose precision*

Comment: No, they are integers, but python handles that intelligently, so there is no overflow, and no loss of precision.

Comment: You've computed *1001th* number, and I've done `1000th`, note that  `enumerate(f())` starts from `0`, not from `1`; another issue is that in the question `f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1` and usually we declare `f(0) = 1, f(1) = 1` so the *new defined* `fibo(x)` is *standard* `fibo(x-1)`. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fibonacci+999

Comment: No, this is incorrect. f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 2, ... and f(1000) is the number I gave. What does f(3) return in you function?

Comment: you're right, `f(0) = 0`, not `f(1) = 0`

Comment: easy to get confused, as it does not match the fibonacci definition.

Answer (score 1):

100th Fibonacci number is a *huge value*, so `BigInteger` (C#) or its analogue is required. C# implementation can be something like this (I doubt if it'll be accepted as homework code).

```
private static IEnumerable<BigInteger> fibo() {
  yield return 0;
  yield return 1;

  BigInteger first = 0;
  BigInteger second = 1;

  while (true) {
    BigInteger result = first + second;

    first = second;
    second = result;

    yield return result;
  }
}

// Skip(1000) since it's defined that f(0) == 0 - unusual sequence starting;
// in mathematics sequences usually started from the 1st item
Console.Write(fibo().Skip(1000).FirstOrDefault().ToString());
```

The answer is

> 43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875

Comment: Hello Dmitry,
Thank you.
I have revised the question, could you please take a look on the revised question.

Comment: Dmitry, your explanation and solution is fine with my expected result. Good support.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, this calls for bc:

```
#!/usr/bin/bc --quiet

define fib(n) {
auto a,b,i;
if(n<2)return n;a=0;b=1;for(i=1;i<n;++i){c=a+b;a=b;b=c}return b;}

print fib(1000), "\n"
quit
```